# Solving a block diagram problem of an LTI-System

Tags: transfer-function, linear, laplace-transform

I have been trying to solve this particular question for about 2 hours, but I am missing something.[image]

I am supposed to calculate the total transfer function of this network, with the total transfer function defined as Y/X .

The two nodes at the top right confuse me, as in, I couldn't figure out which signal is being transferred to the adder in the middle. I got halfway there before I made a mistake, because my solution indicated either an endless loop or the transfer function wasn't linear.

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Comment: The output of the summing junction in the middle of the diagram is Y(s). Now determine all the inputs to this junction, and add/subtract them as indicated.

Comment: I tried that, but I am not sure of the answer I found. If b is the adder in the middle, then b = aH2 - c + Y(s), but it wouldn't make sense, with a being the adder to the left.

Comment: a,b,c are confusing. Write everything in terms of the H's, X, and Y. For example, the output of H3 is (X+Y.H1)H3

Comment: The adder in the middle seems to be wrong: The equation is: \$Y(s) = Y(s) + ...\$ which seems not to be correct.

Comment: @Martin Rosenau, There are terms to the right of Y=Y+ ... that contain Y. If you are still uncomfortable with it, remove the arrow between Y and the middle adder, and change the H4 block to (H4-1)? That amounts to the same thing. Try setting H4=3, say.

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to show you a general way to solve such problems. It's always helpful to define auxiliary variables at the outputs of the adders. You have three adders, but the output of the adder in the middle is the system's output \$Y(s)\$, so you need only two auxiliary variables. \$A_1(s)\$ is the output of the left-most adder, and \$A_2(s)\$ is the output of the bottom adder. For each adder you get one equation (for the sake of convenience and readability, I leave out the argument \$s\$):

$$\begin{align}A_1&=X+H_1Y\\
Y&=H_2A_1-A_2+Y\\
A_2&=H_3A_1+H_4Y\end{align}$$

It is straightforward to solve these equations for the unknown total transfer function

$$H(s)=\frac{Y(s)}{X(s)}=\frac{H_2(s)-H_3(s)}{H_4(s)-H_1(s)[H_2(s)-H_3(s)]}$$

Note that this result is identical to the one presented in [hypfco's answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/277145/22061).